# How can I retrieve XenServer Alerts from SDK/API or CLI

Tags: xenserver, alerts

Is there any way to retrieve alerts infomations from xenserver, such as API or CLI.
[Alerts in XenCenter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95JjO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to use the email alert notification via Citrix XenCenter (pool setting). Another way is the use of syslog forwarding, which is a per-host setting ("log destination" tab in XS-host properties).